# nullreferenceexception was unhandled while pulling connection string from app.config VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, connection-string, app-config, nullreferenceexception

I've been struggling with getting connected using an app.config instead of hardcoding since yesterday evening and I either can't find any more info on the net that helps or I'm too new to understand it all.

The exception is occurring on the line assigning the connectionstring to 'returnvalue'.

```
Imports System.Configuration

Imports System.Data.SqlClient

Public Class Form1

Public Shared Function GetConnectionStringByName( _
ByVal con As String) As String
    Dim returnvalue As String

    returnvalue = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings(con).ConnectionString
    MessageBox.Show(returnValue)

    Return returnValue

End Function
```

Here is the app.config also

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
 <configuration>
<startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0,Profile=Client" />
</startup>

<connectionStrings>
  <clear />
  <add name="con"  
  connectionString="Data Source=DBT07P;InitialCatalog=WeeklyDev_08012011;User Id=user;Password=Pass;"       
       providerName="System.Data.ProviderName"/>
</connectionStrings>

</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the method variable `con` is not set to a value that corresponds to a value in your ConnectionStringSettingsCollection.

If the code that calls `GetConnectionStringByName` sets `con` to the string "con" you should be fine, since "con" is a member of your ConnectionStringSettingsCollection.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am still a newb at this. I wasn't able to figure out what you meant by setting con to the string "con", but I finally managed to solve it by assinging directly as a sqlconnection. I think I was over estimating the complexity of it all.

Comment: @Reggie I'm glad you found a solution.  What I meant was that the function parameter `con` would need to be set to "con", like this: `Call GetConnectionStringByName("con")`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating a function for the getting the connection string as in my initial question's example, I ended up changing things up a little.

My XML now looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
<appSettings>
<add key="connect" value="Data Source=DBT07P;Initial Catalog=WeeklyDev_08012011;User  Id=user;Password=Pass;"/>
</appSettings>
</configuration>
```

and I am using "System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("connect")" in place of where my hard coded connection strings were in my code.

So This:

```
Dim returnvalue as new sqlconnection(Data Source=DBT07P;Initial Catalog=WeeklyDev_08012011;User  Id=user;Password=Pass;)
```

Now looks like this:

```
Dim returnvalue As New SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("connect"))
```